# Считывание комбинации клавиш программой свёрнутой в трей

Tags: c#, winforms, hook

Здравствуйте! Мне бы хотелось, чтобы моя [недо]программа, которая уже свёрнута в трей выполняла определённые события при нажатии определённых комбинаций клавиш. Рыскал с тыкнете, натыкался на WinAPI, глобальные хуки(hook) (Может быть это вообще два одинаковых способа). Короче, так  и не понял как работать с этими хуками. Код в них для меня вообще не понятен, а описания статей для совсем чайников не нашёл(Нашёл один, но там создавался хук для другого применения). Ну так, может быть, есть способ обойтись без этих хуков и найти что-то полегче? А если нет, то тогда дайте, пожалуйста, каких-то статеек (если есть) по созданию хука на сочетание двух клавиш (А то везде только на всю клавиатуру с мышкой пихают).

Ещё слышал о GetAsyncKeyState, но по нему ещё ничего не искал. просто увидел, что он тоже считывает нажатие клавиш в любом состоянии формы. Если это так, то можно тоже немного хороших статеек про эту функцию.

Comment: Вопрос был решён здесь: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2170178.html